# Cosa significa "spicchi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, nouns, vocabulary

Nel racconto *La conchiglia* di Marisa Madieri ho letto:

> «Vedendo che la popolazione dell'isola andava lentamente espandendosi e rendendosi conto che altre migrazioni erano impossibili, per evitare future contese pensò di dividere il territorio in *spicchi*, partendo dal centro verso la costa assegnando a ciascun villaggio uno di questi *spicchi*.»

Qual è il significato di *"spicchi"* in questo contesto? Ho cercato il vocabolo  *"spicco"* nel dizionario, ma non ho trovato nulla che abbia a che vedere con questo contesto.

Comment: Adesso capisco che il vocabolo che dovevo cercare era *"spicchio"* e non *"spicco"*.

Comment: Effettivamente il plurale è uguale. "Spicco" come sostantivo *esiste*, deriva dal verbo "spiccare" e significa "evidenza, rilievo". Comunque si usa poco e praticamente solo (che io sappia) in espressioni come "un giocatore di spicco" (un giocatore che spicca, che si distingue per il suo valore o per qualche altra caratteristica). Il plurale è sì "spicchi", almeno teoricamente, ma mi riesce difficile immaginarmi un'espressione in cui si possa usare.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In questo caso il singolare è "[**spicchio**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spicchio/)", tipicamente si riferisce a una delle parti in cui si può dividere un agrume, ad esempio un'arancia o un mandarino (cfr. [immagine](http://www.freshplaza.it/images/2013/0227/orange_slices.jpg)).

Per estensione si può anche utilizzare per indicare una parte di un tutto, soprattutto se si tratta di una cosa circolare divisa in parti triangolari (ad esempio una pizza).

Comment: Uh! Adesso capisco il mio errore! Ho corretto il titolo della domanda in modo che non cambi il significato. Non so se dovrei cambiare anche il corpo della domanda.

Comment: Potresti fare un edit in cui spieghi l'equivoco e chiudere la domanda.